# How would you merge a set of arrays that represent a hierarchy into an actual hierarchy

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am trying to create a hierarchical interface form a datasource that provides the information as separate arrays that represent levels.

I'm just looking for some inspiration or ideas on how to approach this problem. I've tried a few things with no success.

source :

```
[
  [{id:1}, {id:2}, {id:3}],
  [{id:1}, {id:2}, {id:4}],
  [{id:5}, {id:6}],
  [{id:5}, {id:7}, {id:8}]
]
```

desired result:

```
[
  {
    "id":1,
    "children": [
      {
        "id": 2,
        "children": [
          {
            "id": 3
          },
          {
            "id": 4
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  },{
    "id": 5,
    "children": [
      {
        "id": 6
      },
      {
        "id": 7,
        "children": [
          {
            "id": 8
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Comment: i do not really see a relation between the array and those object structures

Comment: In the source array, the index represents depth. ie "1" and "5" are first tier items, "2", "6" and "7" are second-tier items, "3", "4" and "8" are third-tier items.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a functional two-step process that first converts it to this format:

```
// this isn't even my final form(at)!
{
  1: {
    2: {
      3: {},
      4: {}
    }
  },
  5: {
    6: {},
    7: {
      8: {}
    }
  }
}
```

and then converts that to the final format:

```js
function hierarchy (paths) {
  const root = paths.reduce(
    (root, nodes) => (
      nodes.reduce(
        (root, { id }) => root[id] = root[id] || {}, root
      ), root
    ), {}
  );
  
  return function recurse (root) {
    return Object.entries(root).reduce((root, [id, dir]) => {
      const children = recurse(dir);
      root.push(Object.assign({ id }, children.length > 0 ? { children } : {}));
      return root;
    }, []);
  }(root);
}

let source = [
  [{id:1}, {id:2}, {id:3}],
  [{id:1}, {id:2}, {id:4}],
  [{id:5}, {id:6}],
  [{id:5}, {id:7}, {id:8}]
];

console.log(hierarchy(source));
```

Comment: The solution I described ( badly ) in my other comment was much less efficient. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Generally you should loop over each of the 4 elements.  And for each element, create the tree.  Since the original array is fixed to 3 elements, I did not loop over it, I just assumed it was going to be 3 elements.

Something like:

```
function push_child(a,b) {
   if (a && !a.children) {
       a.children=[];
   }
   a.children.push(b);
}
let data = [
  [{id:1}, {id:2}, {id:3}],
  [{id:1}, {id:2}, {id:4}],
  [{id:5}, {id:6}],
  [{id:5}, {id:7}, {id:8}]
];
let long_data = []
for (let x=0; x<data.length; x++) {
    long_data.push(data[x][0]);
    push_child(long_data[x], data[x][1]);
    push_child(long_data[x].children, data[x][2]);
}
```

results in:

```
[{"id":1,"children":[{"id":2}]},{"id":1,"children":[{"id":2}]},{"id":5,"children":[{"id":6}]},{"id":5,"children":[{"id":7}]}]
```

Comment: Unfortunately I am dealing with arrays of varying lengths, and and also have the need to remove any duplication possible. This solution does, however, suggest some handy methods that I will try out to continue testing ( eg. the separated push_child function ).

Answer (score 0):

For now I have come to a solution using lodash's _.uniqBy method and some odd array walking/manipulation which I find king of hard to describe. Not a great way to end an SO post I know. I'll give it a shot though...

1. I use _.uniqBy to create a unique list of each "Layer". A layer is an array of items at a given depth, removing duplicates.
2. While doing so I also save a copy of each item's "hierarchy", the original array that it came form.
3. Lastly I walk backwards at the list of layers. For each layer i populate the previous layers "children" by filtering the current layer down to those that have it listed in their "hierarchy".

This probably only works because in this system items never live at different layers. Anyway, not sure if this will ever help anyone but I managed to help myself so, yay.